# IEEE Documents as book Chapters

Tags: ieeetran, books

I use the \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} which produces neat double-column papers but would like to make a book/monograph that way (a book collection of papers in which individual papers are chapters). Is there a template for that? Thanks.

Comment: The option `twocolumn` will produce double-column documents in virtually all of the major document classes.

Comment: It doesn't work the same way in other classes. I prefer to retain the IEEE template format.

Comment: And what is "it"?  I assume you can mimic the IEEE format in all the important respects ... and probably with greater ease than forcing a style-option pair meant for a conference paper to turn into a book.  (However, I've not used the class myself, so I'm only thinking in terms of the headers/footers and styles for sectional divisions; maybe there are other features you want.)

Comment: @jon, thanks for the help but I am looking for someone familiar with the IEEE template.

Comment: The reason is that I can have a book yet publish chapters as separate papers on ArXiv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, then you can use `combine` package. This is the sample code to create collection of papers...**[deleted]**.

> Edited
>
> redefine section command to behave like a chapter.
>
> Main document

```
\documentclass[colclass=IEEEtran,12pt, a4paper]{combine}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}


\renewcommand{\section}[1]
    { %
        \refstepcounter{section}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\thesection}{I}}{}{\cleardoublepage}
        \twocolumn[ %
            \begin{@twocolumnfalse} %               
                \huge \textbf{Chapter \thesection. \\ [0.5\baselineskip]#1\\ [\baselineskip]}
            \end{@twocolumnfalse} %
        ]
    }

\begin{document}    
    \title{Collection of IEEEtran articles}
    \author{Asis Pattisahusiwa}
    \date{\today}

    \maketitle

    \begin{papers}
        \import{test}
    \end{papers}

\end{document}
```

> IEEEtran documents

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}    
    \section{IEEEtran section 1}
    \lipsum[1-5]

    \section{IEEEtran section 2}
    \lipsum[1-5]

    \section{IEEEtran section 3}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: How about a Book in that format with the sections as chapters? Thanks.

Comment: I still not clear about your problem. I've modified the answer

Comment: Thanks! But not quite it: you need the title of the paper to become chapter not sections.

Comment: you have mentioned in the previous comment that the section as a chapter. Do you need the chapter in format `Chapter xx. Article title` or just `Article Title` like in my previous answer.

Comment: This is not working at all. I have a structure, \documentclass{book}, with its pagination, tables etc.,  but would like to integrate all the robustness of IEEE tran. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to use \documentclass[onecolumn]{book} yet format the various chapters as IIEE tran?